# Generate parent child diagram using JSON data

Tags: python, json, graph

Basically, I have a complex `JSON` which has `nodes` and `edges`. `edges` has the relationship and `nodes` has the source. Using these data, I would like to draw the Parent child graph. It has to work any level / depth. Prasing nested json is new to me. I am looking for effective right approach. I thought of preparing parent child in the Pandas frame work and write the SQl to buil the tree. But I feel there should be other right way to achive this
I edited the Table_5 instead of S2DCMWorkflow to avoid confusion.
I have drawn the tree diagram. My end goal is to show this tree in web UI . For that i want to collect the data parent child level.

```json
{"graph": {"depthComputed": 1,
           "depthRequested": 2,
           "edges": [{"source": "a84a8484-63e8-43c8-9b20-90302a768537",
                      "target": "e4a8ffc8-c13b-49cc-a11a-af8f0212acea"},
                     {"source": "c5084be9-b3ed-486a-a078-534690507d0d",
                      "target": "e4a8ffc8-c13b-49cc-a11a-af8f0212acea"},
                     {"source": "c4679e97-55af-4d99-9458-6d694cb3de4e",
                      "target": "e4a8ffc8-c13b-49cc-a11a-af8f0212acea"},
                     {"source": "e4a8ffc8-c13b-49cc-a11a-af8f0212acea",
                      "target": "0c5fe88a-ad7c-44db-ab03-e9ceaa5900c6"}],
           "nodes": [{"_id": "0c5fe88a-ad7c-44db-ab03-e9ceaa5900c6",
                      "_type": "DataSourceNode",
                      "name": "Table_4"},
                     {"_id": "a84a8484-63e8-43c8-9b20-90302a768537",
                      "_type": "DataSourceNode",
                      "name": "Table_1"},
                     {"_id": "c5084be9-b3ed-486a-a078-534690507d0d",
                      "_type": "DataSourceNode",
                      "name": "Table_2"},
                     {"_id": "c4679e97-55af-4d99-9458-6d694cb3de4e",
                      "_type": "DataSourceNode",
                      "name": "Table_3"},
                     {"_id": "e4a8ffc8-c13b-49cc-a11a-af8f0212acea",
                      "_type": "ExecutionNode",
                      "agentInfo": {"name": "spline", "version": "0.6.1"},
                      "name": "Table_5",
                      "systemInfo": {"name": "spark", "version": "2.4.8"}}]},
 "info": {"application": "dsfasfasdafadffafsafaa",
          "targetDataSourceId": "0c5fe88a-ad7c-44db-ab03-e9ceaa5900c6",
          "timestamp": 3454345343555}}
```

Expected output (print parent child relationship):

[image: Child Parent]

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to perform some depth first search for all the targets. But the explanation of what you want doesn't match your output, because `S2DCMWorkflow` is not included in the answer, but it is the direct child of `Table_4`. It would help if you could add some more explanation/ example(s) of what you expect. For example a visual graph with the expected answer.

Comment: 1. Clarify how exactly you want to draw the diagram - PNG or vector, static of interactive, do you have any chart library preference?
2. Show what you've tried and what issues you encountered. Do not expect somebody else to write a solution for you from the ground.

Comment: sorry I am not looking for code. lookig for right approach in Python ( as I am SQL guy).